# How to check in argparse if a command line parameter is set from default?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, argparse

I'm using argparse to parse the command line in a Python 3 program. After calling parse_args() I need to figure out whether the values in the returned namespace has been set on the command line or because a default has been applied. How do I do that?

For instance if I add an argument and parse the command line like this:

```
p.add_argument('--loglvl', help = "Set log level", default='warning')
p.add_argument('-t', '--test', help = "Run in test mode", action = 'store_true')

vals = p.parse_args()
```

If vals.test == True I need to know whether it was set from the default value, because it wasn't specified on the command line or if it was set because the command line contained something like this:

```
-t
```

or

```
--test
```

Or if vals.loglvl == 'warning' I need to know if the loglvl argument was left out of the command line or if the command line contains something like this:

```
--loglvl=warning
```

How do I do that? Preferably without having to write my own command line  parser. In other words: Is there something in the parser, or the returned namespace, which contain a list of the arguments supplied on the command line.

Comment: No, while `parse_args` does keep track of which arguments it has seen, this is a local variable and not available to you.  The best I can recommend is stick with the default default, `None`, and test for that.  Your user can't supply that value.  `args.test is None` is a good test.

Comment: @hpaulj: If I understand you correctly, you're basically saying that I can't use the default system in argparse, if I need to detect if it has been used. Is that correct?

Comment: At the start of parsing, the defauls are assigned to the namespace.  The user values overwrite those. At the end any values that are strings and match the defaults are passed through the `type` function.  So there's nothing there to help you.

Comment: @hpaulj: That's not what I wanted to hear. :-) I'll have to make do with not using the argparse-default-system then. Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: default for 'store_true' is False.  So True means the user provided it.

Comment: If it's important to know that the user gave 'warning' don't use it as the default. `default` lets you get a useful value regardless whether the user specified a value or not.  It's supposed to save checking values after parsing.  If you are going to check anyways, don't bother with a special default.

Comment: @hpaulj: Those were only examples. I don't know all the possible arguments, or their values, at time of coding. So I need a general way to handle it, since I can't rely on prior knowledge about each individual argument.

Comment: I might add that the parser just uses the `seen_list` to check if all `required` arguments have been seen.  Feel free to look at the code yourself.